# Pywinauto 0.6.0 - select all Edit control

Tags: pywinauto

I am struggling to do automation for a Desktop application (built by PowerBuilder) as I want to extract data from the desktop application. Is it possible to do these option with Pywinauto
* Select all control with class_name = 'Edit'
* Select control by the location?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean saying `Select control by the location`? By rectangle - it's not easily possible, by all descendants of the top window - it's easy, just use method `descendants(...)` this way:

```
edit_controls = app.YourWindowTitle.descendants(control_type="Edit")
```

Further you can use standard Python `for` loop or list comprehension to filter target controls in by the rectangle.

```
for edit in edit_controls:
    if satisfies_your_condition(edit.rectangle()):
        pass # do something
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This gave me another hope to continue.